# Custom markers with Flutter Google Maps plugin

Tags: google-maps, plugins, flutter

Is there a way to display custom markers with the official [Flutter Google Maps plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter) on the map? Can't find any way to do it based on the documentation.

Comment: Use assert to implement your custom image    mapController.addMarker(MarkerOptions(
            position:
            LatLng(9....., 78....),
            icon:BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("assets/pin.png")));

Comment: @lemuriyan your asset is being loaded using this ?

Comment: Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56534916/3150830) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58481833/3150830) to see how to implement custom markers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
BitmapDescriptor customIcon;

// make sure to initialize before map loading
BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(size: Size(12, 12)),
        'assets/images/car-icon.png')
    .then((d) {
  customIcon = d;
});

final nearbyCarsLocation = [
  LatLng(24.9286825, 67.0403249),
  LatLng(24.985577, 67.0661056), //24.9294892,67.0391903,18.73z
];

void _getNearByCars() {

  for (var i = 0; i < nearbyCarsLocation.length; i++) {
    var now = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    _markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(nearbyCarsLocation[i].toString() + now.toString()),
      position: nearbyCarsLocation[i],
      // infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: address, snippet: "go here"),
      icon: customIcon ));
  }
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Hope this will help in getting custom nearby localities

Comment: I am getting The function 'ImageConfiguration' isn't defined.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using:

```
controller.addMarker(MarkerOptions(
  icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("images/restaurant.png"),
  position: LatLng(40.017870, -105.278350),
));
```

It works fine on Android, but it doesn't work on iOS.

Comment: is there any option to control icon size?

Comment: @Daniel.V Technically you should be able to change the size based on your asset size, but for now (for me at least) it's not working on the Android. The descriptor implementation is not figuring out what's the proper path to the asset based on the device resolution. Also the current plugin for GMaps is more for a "hello wrold" demo rather than a full app. There's a lot of work to be done on it.

Comment: Can't we just use a Widget :-|

Comment: fromAsset is deprecated. Use fromAssetImage instead

Comment: Why not on iOS?

Comment: it only works fine on you

Answer (score 9):

`BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset` is [deprecated](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/lib/src/bitmap.dart#L61)

Use `BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage` instead.

It respects the device DPI when choosing the appropriate asset. See [Declaring resolution-aware image assets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#resolution-aware).

Answer (score 7):

Algo asi 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajuo0HjN3lY&t=905s

```
BitmapDescriptor icon;


@override
  void initState() {
    getIcons();
    super.initState();
  }


// Cargar imagen del Marker
  getIcons() async {
    var icon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 3.2),
        "assets/images/markeruser.png");
    setState(() {
      this.icon = icon;
    });
  }


// Crear Marker
  createMarkers() {
    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("MarkerCurrent"),
        position: currentLocation,
        icon: icon,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: "Mi Ubicacion",
            snippet:
                "Lat ${currentLocation.latitude} - Lng ${currentLocation.longitude}"),
        draggable: true,
        onDragEnd: onDragEnd,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Flutter widgets for custom markers with this class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

/// This just adds overlay and builds [_MarkerHelper] on that overlay.
/// [_MarkerHelper] does all the heavy work of creating and getting bitmaps
class MarkerGenerator {
  final Function(List<Uint8List>) callback;
  final List<Widget> markerWidgets;

  MarkerGenerator(this.markerWidgets, this.callback);

  void generate(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => afterFirstLayout(context));
  }

  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    addOverlay(context);
  }

  void addOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    OverlayState overlayState = Overlay.of(context);

    OverlayEntry entry;
    entry = OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) {
          return _MarkerHelper(
            markerWidgets: markerWidgets,
            callback: (List<Uint8List> bitmapList) {
                // Given callback function
                callback.call(bitmapList);
                
                // Remove marker widget stack from Overlay when finished
                entry.remove();
              },
          );
        },
        maintainState: true);

    overlayState.insert(entry);
  }
}

/// Maps are embeding GoogleMap library for Andorid/iOS  into flutter.
///
/// These native libraries accept BitmapDescriptor for marker, which means that for custom markers
/// you need to draw view to bitmap and then send that to BitmapDescriptor.
///
/// Because of that Flutter also cannot accept Widget for marker, but you need draw it to bitmap and
/// that's what this widget does:
///
/// 1) It draws marker widget to tree
/// 2) After painted access the repaint boundary with global key and converts it to uInt8List
/// 3) Returns set of Uint8List (bitmaps) through callback
class _MarkerHelper extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Widget> markerWidgets;
  final Function(List<Uint8List>) callback;

  const _MarkerHelper({Key key, this.markerWidgets, this.callback})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MarkerHelperState createState() => _MarkerHelperState();
}

class _MarkerHelperState extends State<_MarkerHelper> with AfterLayoutMixin {
  List<GlobalKey> globalKeys = [];

  @override
  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) {
    _getBitmaps(context).then((list) {
      widget.callback(list);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 0),
          child: Material(
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
            child: Stack(
              children: widget.markerWidgets.map((i) {
                final markerKey = GlobalKey();
                globalKeys.add(markerKey);
                return RepaintBoundary(
                  key: markerKey,
                  child: i,
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }

  Future<List<Uint8List>> _getBitmaps(BuildContext context) async {
    var futures = globalKeys.map((key) => _getUint8List(key));
    return Future.wait(futures);
  }

  Future<Uint8List> _getUint8List(GlobalKey markerKey) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
    markerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    var image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2.0);
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  }
}

/// AfterLayoutMixin
mixin AfterLayoutMixin<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => afterFirstLayout(context));
  }

  void afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context);
}
```

usage example

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:map_marker_sample/gist/Gist.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  List<Marker> markers = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            GoogleMap(
              initialCameraPosition:
                  CameraPosition(target: LatLng(45.811328, 15.975862), zoom: 8),
              markers: markers.toSet(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    MarkerGenerator(markerWidgets(), (bitmaps) {
      setState(() {
        markers = mapBitmapsToMarkers(bitmaps);
      });
    }).generate(context);
  }

  List<Marker> mapBitmapsToMarkers(List<Uint8List> bitmaps) {
    List<Marker> markersList = [];
    bitmaps.asMap().forEach((i, bmp) {
      final city = cities[i];
      markersList.add(Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(city.name),
          position: city.position,
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bmp)));
    });
    return markersList;
  }
}

// Example of marker widget
Widget _getMarkerWidget(String name) {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0),
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3, vertical: 1.5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      ),
      child: Text(
        name,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// Example of backing data
List<City> cities = [
  City("Zagreb", LatLng(45.792565, 15.995832)),
  City("Ljubljana", LatLng(46.037839, 14.513336)),
  City("Novo Mesto", LatLng(45.806132, 15.160768)),
  City("Varaždin", LatLng(46.302111, 16.338036)),
  City("Maribor", LatLng(46.546417, 15.642292)),
  City("Rijeka", LatLng(45.324289, 14.444480)),
  City("Karlovac", LatLng(45.489728, 15.551561)),
  City("Klagenfurt", LatLng(46.624124, 14.307974)),
  City("Graz", LatLng(47.060426, 15.442028)),
  City("Celje", LatLng(46.236738, 15.270346))
];

List<Widget> markerWidgets() {
  return cities.map((c) => _getMarkerWidget(c.name)).toList();
}

class City {
  final String name;
  final LatLng position;

  City(this.name, this.position);
}
```

source Link: https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/creating-custom-markers-on-google-maps-in-flutter-apps

github repository :https://github.com/itsJoKr/markers_generator_sample

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I've been trying to do it for hours and finally found an answer with a complete example. I change the below line;   var boundary =
        markerKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
    var image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2.0);

Answer (score 2):

as per new plugin BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("images/restaurant.png") is not working properly so refer this [link](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart) and find my solution.

```
Future<BitmapDescriptor> _getAssetIcon(BuildContext context) async {
final Completer<BitmapDescriptor> bitmapIcon =
    Completer<BitmapDescriptor>();
final ImageConfiguration config = createLocalImageConfiguration(context);

const AssetImage('assets/red_square.png')
    .resolve(config)
    .addListener((ImageInfo image, bool sync) async {
  final ByteData bytes =
      await image.image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
  final BitmapDescriptor bitmap =
      BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
  bitmapIcon.complete(bitmap);
});

return await bitmapIcon.future;}
```

and use this like this

```
void _add(LatLng position,String address) async{
final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId('1');
BitmapDescriptor markericon = await _getAssetIcon(context);

// creating a new MARKER
final Marker marker = Marker(
  markerId: markerId,
  position: position,
  infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: address, snippet: 'go here'),
  icon: markericon
);

setState(() {
  _markers[markerId] = marker;
});}
```

hope it work for you.

Comment: is there no easyier way?

Comment: Hi @kapil-singh Can you provide complete example?

Answer (score 1):

Actually only the commented code of the [example repository of google_maps](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/marker_icons.dart) works...because the flutter sdk have some change in APIs (well im currently in 1.8)

So, this is the function, the same that kapil answer with some changes in APIs, you only need change the line 'assets/red_square.png' for your image route.

```dart
   Future<BitmapDescriptor> _getAssetIcon(BuildContext context) async {
   final Completer<BitmapDescriptor> bitmapIcon =
       Completer<BitmapDescriptor>();
   final ImageConfiguration config = createLocalImageConfiguration(context);

   const AssetImage('assets/red_square.png')
       .resolve(config)
       .addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo image, bool sync) async {
     final ByteData bytes =
         await image.image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
     final BitmapDescriptor bitmap =
         BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
     bitmapIcon.complete(bitmap);
   }));

   return await bitmapIcon.future;
 }
```

Probaly if you create a BitMapDescriptor Variable, you only need to call this function the first time, before add markers, but don forget the "await".

Also is recommended put another 2 bigger size images in folders with names(2.0x & 3.0x) you can see the resolution in the [example images](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/assets)

Don't forget uncomment "/assets" in your pubspec.yaml

Comment: I already test not works, I follow step by step copy from https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/marker_icons.dart

Answer (score 1):

**Try this,

```
_createMarkerImageFromAsset("assets/locationMarker.png");

 Future <BitmapDescriptor> _createMarkerImageFromAsset(String iconPath) async {
    ImageConfiguration configuration = ImageConfiguration();
     bitmapImage = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        configuration,iconPath);
    return bitmapImage;
  }
```

**set bitmapImage to marker**

```
 Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('value'),
        icon: bitmapImage,
        position: LatLng(),
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final bitmapIcon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(size: Size(48,48)), 'assets/images/marker.png');
```

```
Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('marker_2'),
        position: LatLng(_position.target.latitude, _position.target.longitude),
        draggable: true,
        icon: bitmapIcon,
      )
```

Try the above code,use asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set a custom marker, you have to use BitmapDiscriptor.This is a pretty simple method it will get you your custom markers on the map.

First, create a variable,

```
late BitmapDescriptor customIcon;
```

then create a method `customMarkers` and add the following code.

```
void customMarker() {
  BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(),'assets/images/filled_circle.png').
  then((value) => {
  customIcon = value
 });
}
```

after that call `customMarker` method inside init state so that its loads your image before map is created.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    // your code here
    customMarker();
  }
```

now when the app starts the image will be stored in your variable and use that variable inside your `Marker` `icon` parameter like shown below:

```
Marker(
  icon : customIcon,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Load assets image as bytes and use `BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

final asset = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/marker.png');
final icon = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(asset.buffer.asUint8List());

      markers.add(
        Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId('id'),
          icon: icon,
          position: LatLng(lat, lng),
        ),
      );

      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing marker icon

```
MarkerOptions(
position: LatLng(41.4219999, 63.0862462),
infoWindowText: InfoWindowText("Yur Title", "Your Content"),
icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset('images/your_image.png',),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) pluging with [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/)

I tried to do it using Google Maps, succeeded of rendering dynamic web assets on the map and the performance was very low.
With MapBox it was superb, and you can use widgets as markers straight away.

Comment: Were you able to have an array of markers show on your map without any performance issues? I am using FAB as my marker...

Comment: Yes, no problems.. didn't use FAB, but container with network image.. The map tiles do load gradually though every time..

Comment: I found there was a huge performance gain when not in debug... FYI..