# Change icon from flutter google maps Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers, google-maps-flutter

How can I change the icon of marker on google_maps_flutter?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the icon size of Google Maps marker in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633404/how-to-change-the-icon-size-of-google-maps-marker-in-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

```
final BitmapDescriptor icon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
    const ImageConfiguration(), 'assets/icon.png');

Marker(
  markerId: MarkerId('marker'),
  position: LatLng(latitude,longitude),
  icon: icon,
)
```