# How to set custom icon google map in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I want to use different markers for the markers in Google Map. I used swich for this, but I got the following error. What is the reason and how can it be done correctly?

ERROR: The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BitmapDescriptor'.

my code:

```
void _mapsCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
_controller.complete(controller);
setState(() {
  markers.clear();
});
setState(() {
  for (int i = 0; i < _mapmodel.length; i++) {
    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(_mapmodel[i].name),
        position:
            LatLng(toDouble(_mapmodel[i].x), toDouble(_mapmodel[i].y)),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: _mapmodel[i].name, snippet: _mapmodel[i].code),
        icon: setCustomMapPin(_mapmodel[i].gsb),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
});}

  Future<BitmapDescriptor> setCustomMapPin(String value) {
switch (value) {
  case 'diamond':
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
        'assets/images/markerDiamond1.png');
    break;
  case 'gold':
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
        'assets/images/markerGold1.png');
    break;
  case 'silver':
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
        'assets/images/markerSilver1.png');
    break;
  case 'bronze':
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
        'assets/images/markerBronze1.png');
    break;
  default:
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
        ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
        'assets/images/markerRed1.png');
    break;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the ***Error*** simply put the `await` keyword in your icon `code`,

```
icon: await setCustomMapPin(_mapmodel[i].gsb),
```

*Hence you are returning future from the `setCustomMapPin` Method, you will have to put `await` keyword.*

UPDATED:-

Add `async` keyword and `await` in your method.

```
void _mapsCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
_controller.complete(controller);
setState(() {
  markers.clear();
});
setState(() async { // add the async keyword here
  for (int i = 0; i < _mapmodel.length; i++) {
    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(_mapmodel[i].name),
        position:
            LatLng(toDouble(_mapmodel[i].x), toDouble(_mapmodel[i].y)),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: _mapmodel[i].name, snippet: _mapmodel[i].code),
        icon: await setCustomMapPin(_mapmodel[i].gsb),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
});}
```

UPDATED 2:- Call your setState after the for loop and marker code.

```
void _mapsCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
_controller.complete(controller);
setState(() {
  markers.clear();
});
  for (int i = 0; i < _mapmodel.length; i++) {
    markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(_mapmodel[i].name),
        position:
            LatLng(toDouble(_mapmodel[i].x), toDouble(_mapmodel[i].y)),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: _mapmodel[i].name, snippet: _mapmodel[i].code),
        icon: await setCustomMapPin(_mapmodel[i].gsb),
        onTap: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
  setState(() {
    
  });
}
```

Comment: not worked.
error : Unexpected text 'await'.
Try removing the text.

Comment: @JavadMahmoodi Everytime you add a await keyword, you have to add async keyword too in your method.

Comment: @JavadMahmoodi Check My Updated Code

Comment: I did as you did, but the code below is displayed under the red line and the error                Error msg:The argument type 'Future<BitmapDescriptor>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BitmapDescriptor'

Comment: @JavadMahmoodi Please Post your Full Code for that file, As I have tested the same code my side and the error is gone this side.

Comment: @JavadMahmoodi Please use any code sharing platform, I dont need your full code, I only need the relevant code for fixing the issue.

Comment: @JavadMahmoodi I have again edited the code, Hope it might help you, You have to add the async in the setState and then the error will be gone.

Comment: hey @JavadMahmoodi Have you tried to add the async in setState ?, As I did above ?

Comment: setState(()  async{
//your code of for loop and marker

 icon: await setCustomMapPin(_mapmodel[i].gsb),
      }
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:coca_cola/model/mapModel.dart';
import 'package:coca_cola/screen/widget/tost.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'package:validators/sanitizers.dart';

class GMap extends StatefulWidget {
  final double x, y;
  GMap({@required this.x, @required this.y});

  @override
  _GMapState createState() => _GMapState();
}

class _GMapState extends State<GMap> {
  List redscoreMap = List();
  bool loading = true;
  BitmapDescriptor customIcon;
  List<Marker> markers = <Marker>[];
  List<Mapmodel> _mapmodel = [];
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getNearOutlats(widget.x, widget.y);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: HexColor('#EF0000'),
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Customer near you',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      body: _buldBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buldBody() {
    if (loading) {
      return SpinKitRotatingCircle(
        color: HexColor('#FE0000'),
        size: 50,
      );
    }
    return Stack(
      children: [
        _googleMap(context),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _googleMap(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        trafficEnabled: true,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: LatLng(widget.x, widget.y), zoom: 16),
        onMapCreated: _mapsCreated,
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _mapsCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async{
    _controller.complete(controller);
    setState(() {
      markers.clear();
    });
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < _mapmodel.length; i++) {
        markers.add(
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(_mapmodel[i].name),
            position:
                LatLng(toDouble(_mapmodel[i].x), toDouble(_mapmodel[i].y)),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: _mapmodel[i].name, snippet: _mapmodel[i].code),
            icon: await setCustomMapPin(_mapmodel[i].gsb),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  Future<BitmapDescriptor> setCustomMapPin(String value) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'diamond':
        return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
            'assets/images/markerDiamond1.png');
        break;
      case 'gold':
        return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
            'assets/images/markerGold1.png');
        break;
      case 'silver':
        return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
            'assets/images/markerSilver1.png');
        break;
      case 'bronze':
        return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
            'assets/images/markerBronze1.png');
        break;
      default:
        return BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
            'assets/images/markerRed1.png');
        break;
    }
  }

  // ignore: missing_return
  Future<BitmapDescriptor> _icon(String value) async {
    switch (value) {
      case 'diamond':
        return await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            ImageConfiguration(), 'assets/images/markerDiamond1.png');
        break;
      case 'gold':
        return await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            ImageConfiguration(), 'assets/images/markerGold1.png');
        break;
      case 'silver':
        return await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            ImageConfiguration(), 'assets/images/markerSilver1.png');
        break;
      case 'bronze':
        return await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            ImageConfiguration(), 'assets/images/markerBronze1.png');
        break;
      default:
        return await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            ImageConfiguration(), 'assets/images/markerRed1.png');
        break;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _getNearOutlats(double x, double y) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var IDLoginPosition = prefs.getString('loginPosition');
    var IDLoginCity = prefs.getString('loginCity');
    var IDLoginCodeString = prefs.getString('loginCode');

    var url =
        "*******";
    var response = await http.post(url,
        body: {'x': x.toString(), 'y': y.toString(), 'city': IDLoginCity});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      try {
        var jsonData = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
        for (var i in jsonData) {
          Mapmodel data = Mapmodel(i['name'], i['code'], i['sm'], i['asm'],
              i['sv'], i['v'], i['x'], i['y'], i['gsb']);

          _mapmodel.add(data);
        }
        //redscoreMap = jsonData;
        setState(() => loading = false);
        print('count data: ${redscoreMap.toString()}');
      } catch (error) {
        toastShow(
            context: context,
            title: 'Error !',
            subTitle:
                'Failure to receive information from the server. Please try again',
            icon: Icons.report_problem,
            backColor: Colors.red);
        setState(() => loading = false);
      }
    } else {
      toastShow(
          context: context,
          title: 'Error !',
          subTitle:
              'Failure to receive information from the server. Please try again',
          icon: Icons.report_problem,
          backColor: Colors.red);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I add async to setState, I get the following error when running the program.

Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (setState() callback argument returned a Future.
The setState() method on _GMapState#975b4 was called with a closure or method that returned a Future. Maybe it is marked as "async".
Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a call to setState(), first execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then synchronously update the state inside a call to setState().)

Comment: Simply Remove your code of for loop and marker from setState, and Write setState below the code, wait Let me show you with a code snippet.

Comment: Please check the updated code 2, Sorry for the old code, As I was busy with some other work, An was in hurry of replying.

Comment: Thank you very much for your good guidance. Only a small size of markers. Is there a way to make them smaller?

Comment: Actually I haven't worked with markers size yet, So I dont have any idea.

Hope this thread helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633404/how-to-change-the-icon-size-of-google-maps-marker-in-flutter