# in Flutter, how to resize a googleMap marker

Tags: flutter, google-maps, width, google-maps-markers

I display in my application a google map and a marker on a predefined position. I also changed the icon of the marker but it is too large and above all does not adapt to the size of the screen and its definition.
I would therefore like to adapt the dimensions of cd nouveau marker to the size of my screen. First of all, how to change its size?
My code is the following:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  ....
  late BitmapDescriptor iconMareaEstLa;
  final List<Marker> _listMk =[];
  ....
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller){
    mapController = controller;
    setState(() {
      _listMk.add(
          Marker(
            markerId: const MarkerId('MKIDPOSMAREA'),
            draggable: false,
            icon: iconMareaEstLa,
            position: (LatLng(posMareaLat,posMareaLng)),
          )
        );
      });
  }
....
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
    BitmapDescriptor
      .fromAssetImage(
        const ImageConfiguration(size:Size(50,50)),
        'images/MareaBlancFondBlanc.png')
      .then((value) => iconMareaEstLa = value);
}
...
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  MediaQueryData queryData;
  queryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
  screenW =queryData.size.width;
  screenH =queryData.size.height;
  return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
          children: [
            GoogleMap(
              markers: Set.of(_listMk),
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              mapType: _currentMapType,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                  target: _center,
                  zoom: 14.0
              ),
            ),
           ....
```

Can someone tell me where and how to specify the dimensions of my new marker.
Merci

YC

Comment: This workaround might help https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34657#issuecomment-615458858

Comment: You may also want to check the duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633404/how-to-change-the-icon-size-of-google-maps-marker-in-flutter