# Flutter Marker Icon Size

Tags: flutter

I tried to change marker icon size but i did not alread find true solutions. I used Uint8list with Google Map. I shared flutter code below this text.
Can you help me :)

```
String imgurl = "http://cdn.arasikackm.com/harita/ankara-cankaya-gop-harita.jpg";
Uint8List bytes = (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(imgurl),)
  .load(imgurl))
  .buffer
  .asUint8List();

  markers.add(
    Marker( //add start location marker
       zIndex: 1,
       draggable: false,
       anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
      markerId: MarkerId(startLocation.toString()),
      position: startLocation2, //position of marker
      infoWindow: const InfoWindow( //popup info 
        title: 'Starting Point ',
        snippet: 'Start Marker',
      ),
     
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(bytes),
      
     
    )
    
  );
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following discussion, It Is used for the google map marker icon.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633404/how-to-change-the-icon-size-of-google-maps-marker-in-flutter#:~:text=Using%20an%20asset&text=final%20Uint8List%20markerIcon%20%3D%20await%20getBytesFromAsset,100%20and%20200%20width%20respectively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633404/how-to-change-the-icon-size-of-google-maps-marker-in-flutter#:%7E:text=Using%20an%20asset&text=final%20Uint8List%20markerIcon%20%3D%20await%20getBytesFromAsset,100%20and%20200%20width%20respectively).

Comment: i examined all information but only solutions with "getBytesFromCanvas", i need to know "NetworkAssetBundle".

Comment: NetworkAssetBundle Creates a network asset bundle that resolves asset keys as URLs relative to the given base URL. This asset bundle does not cache any resources, though the underlying network stack may implement some level of caching itself.

Comment: so is it possible for me to keep the size of the marker fixed while zooming in and out? like http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/4rxqQ/

Comment: @Rutvik if you want to provide any links as reference then add them in comment section