# Flutter: Is it possible to add bitmap image as ground overlay to flutter google map?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, dart-pub

we would like to display a bitmap image in overlay at given lat-long positions on Google map using Flutter. I am using the flutter package google_maps_flutter: 2.2.1, at present the package does not provide a way to implement the feature.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
//////Decalre a default marker
BitmapDescriptor locationpinned = BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker;
```

then create a function for locationpinned to change it to your icon or png/jpeg/jpg or any from asset
e.g.

```
/// put this function on the initState as long as it called to be first on opening
fromAsset() async {
           /// e.g. location of the asset
           final ping = "assets/png/ping.png";
           /// the function to change the icon
           final myCustomicon =
                await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration.empty, ping);
           setState((){
              locationpinned = myCustomicon;
           });
    }
```

then for the marker just call the locationpinned to put on the marker icon

```
    Marker(
     markerId: const MarkerId("myLocation"),
     icon: locationpinned,
     position: LatLng(
     23.1367346328462, 123.1367346328462),
 ),
```

and that's all i hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Here you are adding image to marker, however our requirement is to add bitmap image(contains canvas drawings) to ground overlay. this bitmap image size should be handled based on zoom in/out. if we add image to marker, then the size of marker remains same even if we zoom in/out.-Thanks.

Comment: you might also find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633404/how-to-change-the-icon-size-of-google-maps-marker-in-flutter