# How to set a custom image as icon for gmap marker in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I wanted to add some markers in a gmap on flutter I made. I tried this code but it doesn't work. I have added link in pubspec and picture is in assets too.

```
Future<void> addMarker(
      LatLng mLatLng, String mTitle, String mDescription) async {
    BitmapDescriptor markerbitmap = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      ImageConfiguration(),
      "assets/images/icons/pin.png",
    );
    setState(() async {
      _markers.clear();

      _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId:
              MarkerId((mTitle + "_" + _markers.length.toString()).toString()),
          position: mLatLng,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: mTitle,
            snippet: mDescription,
          ),
          icon: markerbitmap //BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
          ));
    });
  }
```

no marker gets addded on the map but shows this error in debug console

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception:
> setState() callback argument returned a Future. E/flutter ( 7655): The
> setState() method on _HomePageState#3d9e4 was called with a closure or
> method that returned a Future. Maybe it is marked as "async".
> E/flutter ( 7655): Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a
> call to setState(), first execute the work (without updating the
> widget state), and then synchronously update the state inside a call
> to setState(). E/flutter ( 7655): #0      State.setState. package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1112 E/flutter (
> 7655): #1      State.setState
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1128 E/flutter ( 7655): #2
> _HomePageState.addMarker package:mymapp/screens/home_page.dart:417 E/flutter ( 7655):  E/flutter ( 7655):
> E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.dev/google_maps_android_0( 7655):
> Failed to handle method call

Comment: Is SetState on the same page as Map?

Comment: I also just saw this line in your code `setState(() async {`,  setState should never be asynchronous, see: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I DID THIS.
First, create a method that handles the asset path and receives a size (this can be either the width, height, or both, but using only one will preserve ratio).

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromAsset(String path, int width) async {
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(path);
  ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List(), targetWidth: width);
  ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
  return (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png)).buffer.asUint8List();
}
```

Then, just add it to your map using the right descriptor:

```
   final Uint8List markerIcon = await getBytesFromAsset('assets/images/flutter.png', 100);
    final Marker marker = Marker(icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerIcon));
```

REF: [How to change the icon size of Google Maps marker in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633404/how-to-change-the-icon-size-of-google-maps-marker-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in `initState`

```dart
 
 final _controller = Completer<GoogleMapController>();

 var _markers = const <Marker>{};
  Set<Marker> get markers => _markers;
  set markers(Set<Marker> val) {
    setState(() => _markers = val);
  }

...

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeMap();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        ...
        markers: markers,
        ...
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

...

void initializeMap(){
 markers = {
     Marker(
       markerId: MarkerId(UniqueKey().toString()),
       icon: await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
         const ImageConfiguration(),
         'assets/images/icons/pin.png',
       ),
       position: target.target,
       rotation: target.tilt,
     )
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have this error because you are trying to use "Async" in the block of a setState.

you can remove the async and modify your code to this:

```
Future<void> addMarker(
      LatLng mLatLng, String mTitle, String mDescription) async {
    BitmapDescriptor markerbitmap = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      ImageConfiguration(),
      "assets/images/icons/pin.png",
    );
    setState(() *** ----- delete the async here {
      _markers.clear();

      _markers.add(Marker(
          markerId:
              MarkerId((mTitle + "_" + _markers.length.toString()).toString()),
          position: mLatLng,
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(
            title: mTitle,
            snippet: mDescription,
          ),
          icon: markerbitmap //BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
          ));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.dev/google_maps_android_0( 7655): com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.