# How can i change my BitmapDescriptor size, it seems unaffected when i change the size value

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  Future<BitmapDescriptor> _getCustomMarkerIcon(double size) async {
    final icon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      ImageConfiguration(size: Size(size, size)),
      'assets/images/car.png',
    );
    return icon;
  }



    _getCustomMarkerIcon(2).then((icon) {
      setState(() {
        _customIcon = icon;
          _markers = recommended_cars
        .map((e) => _buildMarker(e, recommended_cars.indexOf(e).toString()))
        .toSet();

      });
    });

  
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            GoogleMap(
              zoomControlsEnabled: false,
              myLocationEnabled: false,
              initialCameraPosition: _initialCamPos,
              markers: _markers,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my widget, i passed the value 2 to the size, i tried 5 or 10 but the icon size isn't changing at all.

i was expecting the size to change when i edit the size value but nothing is happening,i genuienly tried everything i don't know where is the issue exactly.

i think it is here

```
    _getCustomMarkerIcon(2).then((icon) {
      setState(() {
        _customIcon = icon;
          _markers = recommended_cars
        .map((e) => _buildMarker(e, recommended_cars.indexOf(e).toString()))
        .toSet();
```

Comment: I also had this issue. The size parameter of ImageConfiguration appears not to do anything as you say. I followed this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53633404/how-to-change-the-icon-size-of-google-maps-marker-in-flutter). Personally I like the no.1 way (Using an asset) on the accepted answer.

Comment: @YukinosukeTakada can you suggest some code changes in mine that i posted? i can't seem to make it work and i followed that thread

Comment: hmmm... i need to check give me a day

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have included the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

following from what I said on the comments:

Change the following code:

```dart
  Future<BitmapDescriptor> _getCustomMarkerIcon(double size) async {
    final icon = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      ImageConfiguration(size: Size(size, size)),
      'assets/images/car.png',
    );
    return icon;
  }
```

to:

```dart
// Import also this
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

  Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromAsset(int width) async {
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/car.png');
    ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(data.buffer.asUint8List(), targetWidth: width);
    ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();
    return (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png))!.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  Future<BitmapDescriptor> _getCustomMarkerIcon(int width) async {
    final Uint8List markerIcon = await getBytesFromAsset(width);
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerIcon);
  }
```

I have tested this and it works! Note since `targetWidth` can only accept integer, the width type is changed from `double` to `int`.