# Flutter custom Google Map marker info window

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am working on Google Map Markers in Flutter.

On the click of each Marker, I want to show a Custom Info Window which can include a button, image etc. But in Flutter there is a property `TextInfoWindow` which only accept `String`.

How can i achieve adding buttons, images to the map marker's `InfoWindow`.

Answer (score 11):

Stumbled across this problem and found a solution which works for me:

To solve it I did write a [Custom Info Widget](https://github.com/Menelphor/CustomInfoWidget/blob/master/custom_info_widget), feel free to customize it. For example with some shadow via [ClipShadowPath](https://gist.github.com/coman3/e631fd55cd9cdf9bd4efe8ecfdbb85a7).

#### Implementation

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

import 'custom_info_widget.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class PointObject {
  final Widget child;
  final LatLng location;

  PointObject({this.child, this.location});
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        "/": (context) => HomePage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  PointObject point = PointObject(
    child:  Text('Lorem Ipsum'),
    location: LatLng(47.6, 8.8796),
  );

  StreamSubscription _mapIdleSubscription;
  InfoWidgetRoute _infoWidgetRoute;
  GoogleMapController _mapController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: const LatLng(47.6, 8.6796),
            zoom: 10,
          ),
          circles: Set<Circle>()
            ..add(Circle(
              circleId: CircleId('hi2'),
              center: LatLng(47.6, 8.8796),
              radius: 50,
              strokeWidth: 10,
              strokeColor: Colors.black,
            )),
          markers: Set<Marker>()
            ..add(Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(point.location.latitude.toString() +
                  point.location.longitude.toString()),
              position: point.location,
              onTap: () => _onTap(point),
            )),
          onMapCreated: (mapController) {
            _mapController = mapController;
          },

          /// This fakes the onMapIdle, as the googleMaps on Map Idle does not always work
          /// (see: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37682)
          /// When the Map Idles and a _infoWidgetRoute exists, it gets displayed.
          onCameraMove: (newPosition) {
            _mapIdleSubscription?.cancel();
            _mapIdleSubscription = Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 150))
                .asStream()
                .listen((_) {
              if (_infoWidgetRoute != null) {
                Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                    .push(_infoWidgetRoute)
                    .then<void>(
                  (newValue) {
                    _infoWidgetRoute = null;
                  },
                );
              }
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
 /// now my _onTap Method. First it creates the Info Widget Route and then
  /// animates the Camera twice:
  /// First to a place near the marker, then to the marker.
  /// This is done to ensure that onCameraMove is always called 

  _onTap(PointObject point) async {
    final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    Rect _itemRect = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & renderBox.size;

    _infoWidgetRoute = InfoWidgetRoute(
      child: point.child,
      buildContext: context,
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      mapsWidgetSize: _itemRect,
    );

    await _mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(
            point.location.latitude - 0.0001,
            point.location.longitude,
          ),
          zoom: 15,
        ),
      ),
    );
    await _mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(
            point.location.latitude,
            point.location.longitude,
          ),
          zoom: 15,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### CustomInfoWidget:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class _InfoWidgetRouteLayout<T> extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {
  final Rect mapsWidgetSize;
  final double width;
  final double height;

  _InfoWidgetRouteLayout(
      {@required this.mapsWidgetSize,
      @required this.height,
      @required this.width});

  /// Depending of the size of the marker or the widget, the offset in y direction has to be adjusted;
  /// If the appear to be of different size, the commented code can be uncommented and
  /// adjusted to get the right position of the Widget.
  /// Or better: Adjust the marker size based on the device pixel ratio!!!!)

  @override
  Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
//    if (Platform.isIOS) {
    return Offset(
      mapsWidgetSize.center.dx - childSize.width / 2,
      mapsWidgetSize.center.dy - childSize.height - 50,
    );
//    } else {
//      return Offset(
//        mapsWidgetSize.center.dx - childSize.width / 2,
//        mapsWidgetSize.center.dy - childSize.height - 10,
//      );
//    }
  }

  @override
  BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    //we expand the layout to our predefined sizes
    return BoxConstraints.expand(width: width, height: height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(_InfoWidgetRouteLayout oldDelegate) {
    return mapsWidgetSize != oldDelegate.mapsWidgetSize;
  }
}

class InfoWidgetRoute extends PopupRoute {
  final Widget child;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final BuildContext buildContext;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final Rect mapsWidgetSize;

  InfoWidgetRoute({
    @required this.child,
    @required this.buildContext,
    @required this.textStyle,
    @required this.mapsWidgetSize,
    this.width = 150,
    this.height = 50,
    this.barrierLabel,
  });

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => Duration(milliseconds: 100);

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => true;

  @override
  Color get barrierColor => null;

  @override
  final String barrierLabel;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    return MediaQuery.removePadding(
      context: context,
      removeBottom: true,
      removeLeft: true,
      removeRight: true,
      removeTop: true,
      child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return CustomSingleChildLayout(
          delegate: _InfoWidgetRouteLayout(
              mapsWidgetSize: mapsWidgetSize, width: width, height: height),
          child: InfoWidgetPopUp(
            infoWidgetRoute: this,
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}

class InfoWidgetPopUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const InfoWidgetPopUp({
    Key key,
    @required this.infoWidgetRoute,
  })  : assert(infoWidgetRoute != null),
        super(key: key);

  final InfoWidgetRoute infoWidgetRoute;

  @override
  _InfoWidgetPopUpState createState() => _InfoWidgetPopUpState();
}

class _InfoWidgetPopUpState extends State<InfoWidgetPopUp> {
  CurvedAnimation _fadeOpacity;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fadeOpacity = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: widget.infoWidgetRoute.animation,
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
      reverseCurve: Curves.easeOut,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: _fadeOpacity,
      child: Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        textStyle: widget.infoWidgetRoute.textStyle,
        child: ClipPath(
          clipper: _InfoWidgetClipper(),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: Center(child: widget.infoWidgetRoute.child),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _InfoWidgetClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height - 20);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0.0, size.height - 10, 10.0, size.height - 10);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2 - 10, size.height - 10);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2 + 10, size.height - 10);
    path.lineTo(size.width - 10, size.height - 10);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width, size.height - 10, size.width, size.height - 20);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 10.0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width, 0.0, size.width - 10.0, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(10, 0.0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to always display your custom info window without tap marker?

Comment: unfortunately it wont and the whole logic is not designed to do this.

Comment: is there any way to do it?

Comment: do you only want to display things on the marker, or does it need some functionallity?

Comment: I want to implement like this marker with custom infowindow.. https://github.com/gsanthosh91/Google-Map-Floating-Info-Window-Uber/blob/master/screenshot.png

Comment: I would simply design this whole object as a marker. Like @Ashildr did in his sollution.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks sooo much! you should upload this to pub.dev! What's the purpose of making a new camera position in the on tap method? Also, why do we have the `onCameraMove`? thanks

Comment: Tapping on a marker gives me the following errors:

Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3524 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.

Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 3530 pos 12: 'route._navigator == null': is not true.

Comment: @Zog have you find any solution ?

Comment: Is it possible to always display your custom info window without tap marker? Yes, it is when you use controller.  GoogleMap(
                              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                                controller.showMarkerInfoWindow(MarkerId('marker_1'));
                              },

Comment: I know this is an old thread
I added a _infoWidgetRoute?.navigator == null check as well before pushing that error was not shown

Answer (score 10):

I stumbled across the same problem just today, I couldn't get a multiline string to show properly in TextInfoWindow. I ended up circumventing the problem by implementing a modal bottom sheet (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html) that shows when you click on a marker, which in my case worked out quite nicely.

I can also imagine many use cases where you'd want to fully customize the marker's info window, but reading this issue on GitHub (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23938) it looks like it's currently not possible, because the InfoWindow is not a Flutter widget.

Comment: I have the same use case and I was thinking to the same solution. I think Google doesn't want developers to use the info window to show a lot of information, but to use instead a bottom sheet like they do on Google maps. Even in native Android the info window is kind of gimped.

Answer (score 6):

You can display marker made of widgets as custom 'info window'. Basically you are creating png image of your widget and displaying it as a marker.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class MarkerInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function getBitmapImage;
  final String text;
  MarkerInfo({Key key, this.getBitmapImage, this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MarkerInfoState createState() => _MarkerInfoState();
}

class _MarkerInfoState extends State<MarkerInfo> {
  final markerKey = GlobalKey();

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getUint8List(markerKey)
        .then((markerBitmap) => widget.getBitmapImage(markerBitmap)));
  }

  Future<Uint8List> getUint8List(GlobalKey markerKey) async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        markerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    var image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2.0);
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
    return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RepaintBoundary(
      key: markerKey,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 29),
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Color(0xFF000000),
          child: Text(
            widget.text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you use this approach you have to make sure you render the widget, because this will not work otherwise. For converting widgets to images - widget has to be rendered in order to convert it. I'm hiding my widget under the map in Stack.

```
return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          MarkerInfo(
              text: tripMinutes.toString(),
              getBitmapImage: (img) {
                customMarkerInfo = img;
              }),
          GoogleMap(
            markers: markers,
 ...
```

Last step is to create a Marker. Data passed from the widget is saved in customMarkerInfo - bytes, so convert it to Bitmap.

```
markers.add(
          Marker(
            position: position,
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(customMarkerInfo),
            markerId: MarkerId('MarkerID'),
          ),
        );
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSQrD.png)

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a solution to create custom marker that doesn’t rely on InfoWindow. ***Although, this approch won’t allow you to add a button on custom marker***.

Flutter google maps plugin lets us use image data / asset to create a custom marker. So, this approach uses drawing on [Canvas](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html) to create a custom marker and using [PictureRecorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PictureRecorder-class.html) to convert the same to a picture, which later on would be used by google maps plugin to render a custom marker.

Sample code to draw on Canvas and convert the same to Image data that can be used by the plugin.

```
void paintTappedImage() async {
    final ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(recorder, Rect.fromPoints(const Offset(0.0, 0.0), const Offset(200.0, 200.0)));
    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(1)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
            const Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, 152.0, 48.0), const Radius.circular(4.0)),
        paint);
    paintText(canvas);
    paintImage(labelIcon, const Rect.fromLTWH(8, 8, 32.0, 32.0), canvas, paint,
        BoxFit.contain);
    paintImage(markerImage, const Rect.fromLTWH(24.0, 48.0, 110.0, 110.0), canvas,
        paint, BoxFit.contain);
    final Picture picture = recorder.endRecording();
    final img = await picture.toImage(200, 200);
    final pngByteData = await img.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
    setState(() {
      _customMarkerIcon = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(Uint8List.view(pngByteData.buffer));
    });
  }

  void paintText(Canvas canvas) {
    final textStyle = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 24,
    );
    final textSpan = TextSpan(
      text: '18 mins',
      style: textStyle,
    );
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: textSpan,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
    textPainter.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: 88,
    );
    final offset = Offset(48, 8);
    textPainter.paint(canvas, offset);
  }

  void paintImage(
      ui.Image image, Rect outputRect, Canvas canvas, Paint paint, BoxFit fit) {
    final Size imageSize =
        Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());
    final FittedSizes sizes = applyBoxFit(fit, imageSize, outputRect.size);
    final Rect inputSubrect =
        Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.source, Offset.zero & imageSize);
    final Rect outputSubrect =
        Alignment.center.inscribe(sizes.destination, outputRect);
    canvas.drawImageRect(image, inputSubrect, outputSubrect, paint);
  }
```

once the marker is tapped, we can replace the tapped image with the new image generated from Canvas. Sample code for the same taken from google maps plugin example app.

```
void _onMarkerTapped(MarkerId markerId) async {
  final Marker tappedMarker = markers[markerId];
  if (tappedMarker != null) {
    if (markers.containsKey(selectedMarker)) {
      final Marker resetOld =
      markers[selectedMarker].copyWith(iconParam: _markerIconUntapped);
      setState(() {
        markers[selectedMarker] = resetOld;
      });
    }
    Marker newMarker;
    selectedMarker = markerId;
    newMarker = tappedMarker.copyWith(iconParam: _customMarkerIcon);
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = newMarker;
    });
    tappedCount++;
  }
}
```

Reference:

[How to convert a flutter canvas to Image](https://github.com/rxlabz/flutter_canvas_to_image).

[Flutter plugin example app.](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example)

[image: Google maps flutter plugin custom marker in action.]

Answer (score 3):

Bellow is 4 step I had implemented for custom InfoWindow on my project

Step 1: Create a stack for GoogleMap and Info Window Custom.

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned.fill(child: GoogleMap(...),),
    Positioned(
      top: {offsetY},
      left: {offsetX},
      child: YourCustomInfoWidget(...),
    )
  ]
)
```

Step 2: When user click Marker calculator position of marker on screen with func:

```dart
screenCoordinate = await _mapController.getScreenCoordinate(currentPosition.target)
```

Step 3: Calculator offsetY, offsetX and setState.

Relate issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41653

```dart
devicePixelRatio = Platform.isAndroid ? MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio : 1.0;

offsetY = (screenCoordinate?.y?.toDouble() ?? 0) / devicePixelRatio - infoWidget.size.width;
offsetX = (screenCoordinate?.x?.toDouble() ?? 0) / devicePixelRatio - infoWidget.size.height;
```

Step 4: Disable Marker auto move camera when tap

```dart
Marker(
   ...
   consumeTapEvents: true,)
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a widget-based info window you need to stack the widget on google map. With the help of `ChangeNotifierProvider`, `ChangeNotifier`, and `Consumer` you can easily rebuild your widget even when the camera moves on google map.

InfoWindowModel class:

```
class InfoWindowModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _showInfoWindow = false;
  bool _tempHidden = false;
  User _user;
  double _leftMargin;
  double _topMargin;

  void rebuildInfoWindow() {
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateUser(User user) {
    _user = user;
  }

  void updateVisibility(bool visibility) {
    _showInfoWindow = visibility;
  }

  void updateInfoWindow(
    BuildContext context,
    GoogleMapController controller,
    LatLng location,
    double infoWindowWidth,
    double markerOffset,
  ) async {
    ScreenCoordinate screenCoordinate =
        await controller.getScreenCoordinate(location);
    double devicePixelRatio =
        Platform.isAndroid ? MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio : 1.0;
    double left = (screenCoordinate.x.toDouble() / devicePixelRatio) -
        (infoWindowWidth / 2);
    double top =
        (screenCoordinate.y.toDouble() / devicePixelRatio) - markerOffset;
    if (left < 0 || top < 0) {
      _tempHidden = true;
    } else {
      _tempHidden = false;
      _leftMargin = left;
      _topMargin = top;
    }
  }

  bool get showInfoWindow =>
      (_showInfoWindow == true && _tempHidden == false) ? true : false;

  double get leftMargin => _leftMargin;

  double get topMargin => _topMargin;

  User get user => _user;
}
```

Complete Example is available on my [blog](https://www.abhishekduhoon.com/2020/06/how-to-create-widget-based-google-maps.html)!

Comment: You may want to clarify **in the post** whether you are the author of the website you linked to, to avoid the possibility of this post being perceived as spam.

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site in your post*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. Please see: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [the help center on self-promotion](/help/promotion). Disclosure must be explicit, but doesn't need to be formal. When it's your own *personal* content, it can just be something like "on my site…", "on my blog…", etc.