# how to draw some markers and make it different each other (flutter google map)

Tags: google-maps, flutter

i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591556/custom-markers-with-flutter-google-maps-plugin) to customize marker on flutter_google_maps and [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/export-your-widget-to-image-with-flutter-dc7ecfa6bafb) to change widget into bytes, since we could change marker [using bytes](https://coletiv.com/blog/use-network-images-as-marker-icons-flutter-google-maps/), not widget.

i actually solve the problem if i use only one type of marker like this:

[image]

but things are different where the requirement design just like this:

[image]

so how do i solve the problem?

here some code i use, but the result output is first image above, not as expected.

-> method to change widget into image

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> keyScaffold = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

Future<Uint8List> _capturePng() async {
    try {
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
      keyScaffold.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
      ByteData byteData =
      await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
      return pngBytes;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

bool rendering = true;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Peta'),
      ),
      body: rendering
          ? renderWidgetToImage()
          : renderGoogleMap()
);
```

-> method to render widget before converted

```
String title;
  Widget renderWidgetToImage() {
    return RepaintBoundary(
      key: keyScaffold,
      child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 10
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
```

-> method to programmatically add marker using widget

```
final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   var arrMarker = <MarkerMap>[
      MarkerMap("Text Widget 3","123",3.59196,98.672226),
      MarkerMap("Text Widget 2","456",3.49196,97.572226),
      MarkerMap("Text Widget 1","789",3.39196,97.772226),
    ];
    for(int i =0; i< arrMarker.length; i++) {
      setState(() {
        this.title = arrMarker[i].title;
      });
 BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
          ImageConfiguration(size: Size(48, 48)), DefaultImageLocation.iconAnalog)
          .then((onValue) async {
        var png = await _capturePng(keyScaffold);
        setState(() {
          this.myIcon = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(png);
          this.rendering = false;
        });
        setState(() {
          _markers.add(
            Marker(
                markerId: MarkerId(arrMarker[i].id),
                position: LatLng(arrMarker[i].pos1, arrMarker[i].pos2),
                icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(png),
            ),
          );

        });
 });
      setState(() {
        this.rendering = true;
      });
}
```

any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: I think you have to follow the 3rd option. Create an image with blue rounded corner and one arrow at bottom and use it as icon under maker configuration.

Comment: @Avijit i hope so, but the image should have text from server dynamically, shown in the second screenshot above as well. is there a way to generate such image in flutter?

Comment: Don't think that is good idea. You may try to add `infoWindow: InfoWindow(title:"Mampang")` inside Marker() and check if it fulfills your needs.

Comment: @Avijit indeed, but that requires users to click markers one by one.. umm nope, i guess infoWindow can't be open more than one item right? but the requirement need them to be opened in same time

Comment: you can open `infoWindow`s all at the same time programmatically. I'll check if I find any code snippet for that.

Comment: @Avijit thanks! so far i've found [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33481) to programmatically open `infoWindow` but unfortunately it still can't open all `infoWindow`s in same time... looking forward for your snippet

Comment: okay, I found google_maps_flutter only supports two events `onTap` and `onDragEnd`, so currently it is not possible using flutter to show InfoWindow programatically. May be you should try creating dynamic image with the text on it and use it as marker icon. Hope this will be helpful: https://codepen.io/ahebler/pen/KzyQBZ

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is now possible using the steps provided in [this blog](https://mohan-smk23.medium.com/custom-dynamic-google-map-markers-in-flutter-use-your-own-widget-5e50d382bc99).

As mentioned in the intro:

> We need to paint a Widget and then convert it to bitmap. But its
> tricky because you cant simply do that. we have to place into widget
> tree and fetch its painted bitmap.

For a rough summary, the steps mentioned were:

> First
> We need to get our bitmaps right after they are drawn. There
> are multiple ways to do this, I use tiny `AfterLayoutMixin` available
> [here](https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout).
>
> Second
> Lets create our custom widget, yay!
>
> My widget accepts name as an parameter. I used ClipPath for the
> triangular Pointer arrow.
>
> Third
> Lets create a location object and list of locations and a
> method to generate widgets from the location list.