# How to add rounded photo markers to Google Maps on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have  a service that will return to me some photo urls. I need to round them and add to Google Maps, as markers.
How can I achieve this in Flutter? How can I make a image rounded before transforming it into a BitmapDescriptor?

Comment: Yes, but how to process it in a circular shape?

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591556/custom-markers-with-flutter-google-maps-plugin

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this: [Custom marker](https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/creating-custom-markers-on-google-maps-in-flutter-apps)

Comment: Author here. This method would work. You would basically show your image in widget like ClipRRect and draw that to bitmap again. A better solution would be to perform rounding on canvas directly without using flutter at all (you just use dart:ui). This is more work though and I don't have examples of that.