# Flutter Google Map multiple circles with ripple and pulse effect

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I am new to flutter development so this question is about Flutter google maps using this package google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1.
I wonder if there is any way to give ripple and pulse effect to the circles of Google Map like this
Link of UI : https://dribbble.com/shots/7199173-Store-Locator

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591556/custom-markers-with-flutter-google-maps-plugin

Comment: No its about custom markers but i want to give ripple effect to multiple circles of google map

Comment: Which are custom markers only you've to replace it with your desired design.

Comment: do you mean provide an animation to the BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(ImageConfiguration(size: Size(12, 12)),
        'assets/images/car-icon.png') instead of car-icon.png ?

Comment: Yes, not sure if you can use widget directly but you can surely use an animated gif.

Comment: okay thanks i will try

Comment: did it work out as expected with animated gif? @jumairahmad

Comment: did it work out as expected with animated gif? @jumairahmad