# How to add a jumping effect in Google map marker flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I would like to animate marker in google map flutter like the below image.
[image]

How to do this in Flutter.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591556/custom-markers-with-flutter-google-maps-plugin

Comment: It appears impossible, as the marker seems to be drawn in the native code. It would be nice if a marker were a widget.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can used this package [animarker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker)

Comment: not useful in this case